# how to deal with timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am doing an application that runs from the console, it counts the number of sundays in every months beetween the dates passed, and outputs only months with 5 sundays. So at the end if there is 6 months that have 5 sundays, it outputs 6. I enter the dates in this format: january 2014 june 2014 and the params are in a txt file passed as a param. I did it in php and it was pretty simple, but in node js, I'm suffering. The CES or CEST is killing me. I'm trying to work with UTC dates only, but I cannot control it and I having strange output. For example if I introduce "january 2014 june 2014" I get two months, but when I introduce "june 2016 february 2017" I get 4, and it should be 3. 
I put a console.log(date) when the program counts five sundays and I get those dates:

```
Sun Mar 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Sun Jun 01 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
2 //the output of months that have 5 sundays

Sun Jul 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sun Oct 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sat Dec 31 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Sat Feb 04 2017 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
4  //the output of months that have 5 sundays
```

as you can see, there are two saturdays, with 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET). This output is really strange and I really don't know how to deal with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Make sure we got a filename on the command line.
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
  process.exit(1);
}
// Read the file and print its contents.
var fs = require('fs'), filename = process.argv[2];
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //split by carriage return
    data = data.split(/[\n\r]+/g);

    data.forEach(function(value){
        var secureDate = securizeData(value);
        var totalDays = getDaysBetweenDates(secureDate[0],secureDate[1],secureDate[2],secureDate[3]);
        calculateSundays(totalDays, secureDate[0],secureDate[1])    
    });

});

/**
 * Description: checks the data and returns it as an array
 * @param {string} data
 * @return {array} data
 */
function securizeData(data){

    //Looks for two strings (months) and two int ( year) matches with regexp 
    var matchCount = data.match(/([a-z]+ [0-9]{4})/g);
    if(matchCount == 0){
        process.exit('Insert a valid input');
    }

    //clean carriage return
    data = data.replace(/[\n\r]+/g,' ',data);
    //clean left over blank spaces
    data = data.replace(/  +/g,' ',data);


    //split data in an array
    data = data.split(' ');

    //check array length
    var nIndex = data.length;

    //returns an array which it's total index number is a pair number or else error
    if(nIndex%2==0){
        return (data);
    }else{
        process.exit('Insert a valid input');
    }
}

/**
 * Description:
 * @param {string} firstMonth
 * @param {int} firstYear
 * @param {string} secondMonth
 * @param {int} secondYear 
 */
function getDaysBetweenDates(firstMonth, firstYear, secondMonth, secondYear){

        var daysFirstDate = getDaysFirstDate(firstMonth, firstYear);
        var daysSecondDate =  getDaysSecondDate(secondMonth,secondYear);
        var daysBetweenDates = substractDays(daysFirstDate,daysSecondDate);
        return daysBetweenDates; 
}

/**
 * Description: substraction of two given unix dates
 * @param {int} daysFirstDate
 * @param {int} daysSecondDate
 * @return {int} days in unix format. Error if first date is later than second 
 */
function substractDays(daysFirstDate,daysSecondDate){

    if(daysFirstDate>daysSecondDate){
        process.exit('First date must be earlier than second date');
    }else{
        var datediff = daysSecondDate-daysFirstDate;
        datediff = datediff/(60*60*24)/1000;
        var roundedNumber = Math.floor(datediff)
        return (roundedNumber);
    }   
}

/**
 * Description: get the first date from day one in unix format
 * @param {string} @firstMonth
 * @param {int} @firstYear
 * @return {int} @date
 */
function getDaysFirstDate(firstMonth,firstYear){
    var month = getMonthFromString(firstMonth,firstYear);
    return (Date.UTC(firstYear, month ,01));
}

/**
 * Description: get the second date from last day of it's month in unix format
 * @param {string} @secondMonth
 * @param {int} @secondYear
 * @return {int} @date2
 */
function getDaysSecondDate(secondMonth,secondYear){

        var secondMonthNumber = getMonthFromString(secondMonth,secondYear);

        //Get last day of the month
        var lastDayMonth = getLastDayOfTheMonth(secondMonthNumber,secondYear);

        //Add last day of the month to secondDate
        return (Date.parse(secondMonth + ' ' + lastDayMonth +', ' + secondYear));

}

/**
 * Description: get month number from a month string
 * @param {string} @month
 * @return {int} @month
 */
function getMonthFromString(mon,year){
   return new Date(Date.parse(mon +" 1, "+year)).getMonth();
}

/**
 * Description: get the Last day of the Month given in params
 * @param {int} @secondYear
 * @param {int} @secondMonthNumber
 * @return {int} UTCDate
 *
 */
function getLastDayOfTheMonth(secondMonthNumber, secondYear){
    var lastDay = new Date(secondYear, secondMonthNumber +1, 0);
    return(lastDay.getUTCDate());
}

/**
 * Description:
 * @param {int} totalDays
 * @param {array} tempDate
 */
function calculateSundays(totalDays,month, year){

    var sundays={ num: '0' , output: '0' };
    var intMonth = { val: new Date(Date.parse(month + year)).getMonth() };
    intMonth.previousVal = intMonth.val;

    var d = Math.floor((new Date(year, intMonth.val,1)).getTime());
/// console.log(e);
//  process.exit();

    var d = new Date(year, intMonth.val, 1);
    var dayOfTheWeek = d.getUTCDay();

    for(var day = 2;day<=totalDays;day++)
    {

        resetSundaysIfMonthIncrease(intMonth, sundays);

        //update sundays
        if(dayOfTheWeek == 6) {
            sundays.num++;
        }

        //if there is 5 days in a month increase output
        if(sundays.num == 5)
        {
            sundays.output++;
            sundays.num = 0;
            console.log(d);
        }

        //increment date
        d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);

        //update Day of the week
        dayOfTheWeek = d.getUTCDay();

        //update Month
        intMonth.val = d.getUTCMonth();
    }

    if(sundays.output == 0)process.exit("Please enter more than one month distance between dates \n");
    else console.log(sundays.output + "\n");
}  

/**
 * description: reset sunday counter to 0 if current month is greater than previous month 
 * @param {Object} intMonth
 * @param {Object} sundays
 */
function resetSundaysIfMonthIncrease(intMonth, sundays)
{   
    if(intMonth.val>intMonth.previousVal)
    {
        intMonth.previousVal = intMonth.val;
        sundays.num = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm seems to convoluted, also javascript months are zero indexed so Jan is 0, Feb is 1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm is to get the first Sunday of the month and see if it's less than 28 days to the end of the month. If so, the month has 4 Sundays, otherwise 5. UTC is irrelevant.

Here's some code, hopefully the comments are sufficient:

```js
/* Return the number of months with 5 sundays between two dates
** specified as year, month where month number is the calendar month,
** Jan = 1, Feb - 2, etc.
**
** @param {number} y0 - start year
** @param {number} y1 - end year
** @param {number} m0 - start month (calendar number)
** @param {number} m1 - end month (calendar number) 
** @returns {number} number of months with 5 Sundays between start and end
*/
function countMonthsWith5Sundays(y0, m0, y1, m1) {
  
  // Create dates for first of start and end month
  var start = new Date(y0, m0-1, 1);
  var end = new Date(y1, m1-1, 1);
  var count = 0;
  
  // If end is before start, swap dates
  if (start > end) {
    var t = start;
 start = end;
 end = t;
  }
  
  // Step month by month from start to end, counting months with 5 Sundays
  while (start <= end) {
    if (sundaysInMonth(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth() + 1) === 5) {
   ++count;
 }
 start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  return count;
}

// Month number is calendar month, jan = 1, feb = 2, etc.
/* Calculate number of Sundays in a month
**
** @param {number} y - year
** @param {number} m - month number (calendar number)
*/
function sundaysInMonth(y, m) {
  // Create date for start of month, move to first Sunday
  var d = new Date(y, m-1, 1);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (d.getDay()? 7 - d.getDay() : 0));
  
  // Get number of days in month, subtract current date and
  // if there are 28 days or more left, there are 5 Sundays
  // Use calendar month number and date of 0 to get last day of
  // month
  var daysInMonth = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
  return daysInMonth - d.getDate() > 27 ? 5 : 4;
}

document.write(countMonthsWith5Sundays(2016,1,2016,6));
```

The above can be easily modified to return a Date representing the fist day or first Sunday in those months that have 5 Sundays.

Comment: You rool!! Thanks Boss!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution to list the months that has 5 sundays revolve around 2 rules:

1. The month should have more than 28 days; and
2. The day of the first sunday should be less than the number of days above 28 in the month.

I have modified your code to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

It would look something like:

```js
// Make sure we got a filename on the command line.
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
  process.exit(1);
}

// Read the file and print its contents.
var fs = require('fs'), filename = process.argv[2];
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //split by carriage return
  data = data.split(/[\n\r]+/g);

  data.forEach(function(value){
    var secureDate = securizeData(value);
    calcSundays(secureDate[0], secureDate[1], secureDate[2], secureDate[3]);
  });
});

/**
 * Description: checks the data and returns it as an array
 * @param {string} data
 * @return {array} data
 */
function securizeData(data){
  //Looks for two strings (months) and two int ( year) matches with regexp 
  var matchCount = data.match(/([a-z]+ [0-9]{4})/g);
  if(matchCount == 0){
    process.exit('Insert a valid input');
  }

  //clean carriage return
  data = data.replace(/[\n\r]+/g,' ',data);
  //clean left over blank spaces
  data = data.replace(/  +/g,' ',data);

  //split data in an array
  data = data.split(' ');

  //check array length
  var nIndex = data.length;

  //returns an array which it's total index number is a pair number or else error
  if(nIndex%2==0){
    return (data);
  }else{
    process.exit('Insert a valid input');
  }
}

/**
 * Description: loop through the months between the start and end dates and count the sundays in each month.
 * @param {string} firstMonth
 * @param {int} firstYear
 * @param {string} secondMonth
 * @param {int} secondYear 
 */
function calcSundays(startMonth, startYear, endMonth, endYear) {
  var intStartMonth = getMonthFromString(startMonth, startYear);
  var intEndMonth = getMonthFromString(endMonth, endYear);
  var date = { 
    month: intStartMonth, 
    year: startYear 
  };
 
  while (date.month <= intEndMonth && date.year <= endYear) {
    var sundays = countSundaysInMonth(date);
    if (sundays == 5) {
      // Log the last sunday of the month with 5 sundays.
      console.log(moment(date).endOf('month').day(-7).format()); 
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Description: count the number of sundays in a month.
 * @param {object} date
 */
function countSundaysInMonth(date) {
  var totDays = moment(date).endOf('month').date();
  if (totDays < 29) return 4;
  var firstSunday = moment(date).day('Sunday').date();
  if (firstSunday <= totDays - 28) return 5;
  return 4;
}

/**
 * Description: get month number from a month string
 * @param {string} @month
 * @return {int} @month
 */
function getMonthFromString(mon,year){
  return new Date(Date.parse(mon +" 1, "+year)).getMonth();
}
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question